# How do I make an exposed drop-down filter filter on a grouped set of date fields?

Tags: views, 9

We have a Drupal 9 View of nodes that have a date field. The node dates will all be for a particular day for one specific week (for an event).

We have the View formatted set to group the dates and this works nice for outputting **all** of the nodes but we need to include a dropdown filter to show a list of the dates in the View and allow it to be filtered to only show nodes of that date.

I know we can add a simple exposed filter on the date field but this is a text or date-pop-up field that requires inputting the data. How can we include an exposed filter that is a drop-down showing only the dates that are in the view?